Why does this JavaScript code cause a memory leak despite cleaning up all references?
I have a question about a memory leak I'm able to create in Google Chrome. By creating a Div element, adding it to the DOM, and removing it later the element is never removed from memory.
const addDiv = () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'test';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    // - Wait to cleanup the DIV
    setTimeout(() => div.remove(), 200);
};

setTimeout(() => addDiv(), 5000);

I've uploaded an image of chrome dev tools showing the DIV in memory.

Below is another image running this function on an interval to show how this can add up.
setInterval(() => addDiv(), 100);


What is strange is that you can fix the memory leak by slowing down the setInterval to a time greater than the promise.
setInterval(() => addDiv(), 300);


Is this a chrome bug, or is this desired Javascript behavior? I don't understand why running the code once on a timeout would keep the Div in memory, but running it forever on an interval frees it.

Also, why New Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200)).then(() => div.remove());? seems an overly obscure way to do setTimeout(() => div.remove(), 200). Just because Promises are a relatively new thing to javascript, doesn't mean you have to use them, especially when the use essentially does nothing useful

If I create a div every second, and then wait 2 seconds to remove that div, I will have a max of 2 divs at a time.
If I wait 12 seconds to remove the div I will have a max of 12 divs at a time. There's never a point in my code that divs are created at an infinitum rate.
When I say "slowing down the setInterval" I'm referring to the code I used from my second picture, where I said I added a setInterval to create the image.

If I create a div every second, and then wait 2 seconds to remove that div, I will have a max of 2 divs at a time. - yeah, true, I broke my brain thinking about it too much :p for some reason I thought the divs would be removed at 2 second intervals - clearly, it being after 5pm on a Friday, I have weekend brain

Over what period are you monitoring the memory usage? looks like 7 seconds, try a couple of minutes, see what happens when a garbage collection or 2 kicks in

@Bravo Unfortunately I've let this go on for over 30 minutes and the DIV's stay in memory.
